# Bootstrap Form Design

Tags: html, css, forms, frameworks, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to redesign my registration form using [bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html). I'm following [this documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html?#typography) to convert my already finished registration page into a bootstrap based page. My registration page is broken into 3 parts, Options/Information/Payment. But I want pages to slide into each other like a slider where you can go back and forth. Something like [this](http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/wizard.html). So how do I break this form into three pieces and slide into each other with bootstrap?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Bootstrap Tabs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) will do what you need.

Comment: ah perfect, just what I need. Now depending on the option they choose on the first page, the second page changes. So is there a way to disable the second tab until they choose an option from the first tab? And also, if they change their choice later on, reload the second tab to reflect the new choice

Comment: Sounds like a separate question (try it yourself first, I guarantee you'll be asked for code).